# Why does lighter air goes up?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, air, gas

If we increase the temperature of a volume of air it will rise up but if we look from molecular level, there kinetic energy has just changed but not thier weight so why they rise up
and do not go in any other direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does hot air rise?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/164593/why-does-hot-air-rise)

Answer (score 1):

Simply speaking, there is no change of mass or not such things are happening. Hot air rises because if we heat gas it expands and starts to diffuse at a high rate(avoiding complications). As the density falls, the air become light and starts to rise up and comparatively dense air come down due to the pull of gravity to take its place and a cycle starts to continue till to an equilibrium is established.